# Cannot resolve symbol moveToNext()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, cursor

What's going on here guys? I've tried cleaning my gradle, I know for a fact that my database contains these columns. It's driving me nuts y'all.

```
public Cursor select_week(int week){
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db1.rawQuery("select " + COL_3 + "," + COL_4 + " from Regular_Season where Week =" + week + ";", null);
    return res;
}
```

`Cursor res = myDb.select_week(week);`

```
while (res.moveToNext()) {
    Button p1_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    p1_button.setText(res.getString(0));

    Button p2_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    p1_button.setText(res.getString(1));

    Button p3_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    p1_button.setText(res.getString(2));

    Button p4_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    p1_button.setText(res.getString(3));
}
```

Comment: are you checked cursor have any row r not ? **using this** `if (cursor.getCount() >0) `.

Comment: Where is the `Cursor res = ...` line, exactly? It needs to be inside a method.

Comment: Gets the same error, "cannot resolve symbol getCount()"

Comment: @MikeM. It is not inside a method. Thank you I think that was the the problem

Comment: Yeah, all that stuff needs to be inside a method.